# SSRS Report SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Help needed to understand why query in ssrs report is not returning rows where column is null,
4 properties specified in report ( title, name, manager, company), report only returns rows where all 4 properties contain a value. ssms shows many user have a value of NULL where manager name should be.

The report has been re-constructed from another report so i did not write the original

````
CREATE TABLE #TempMacro_PV (mask VARCHAR(8000))
CREATE TABLE #TempMacro_PV2 (mask VARCHAR(8000))
CREATE TABLE #TempMacro_PV3 (mask VARCHAR(8000))
CREATE TABLE #TempMacro_PV4 (mask VARCHAR(8000))

         DECLARE @FirstStr NVARCHAR(4000)
         DECLARE @i INT, @j INT
         SET @FirstStr = CAST(N'"& Code.Parameter_GetCodedAttrValues(Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList1_Values.Value) &"' AS NVARCHAR(4000))
         SET @i = - 1
         WHILE @i <> 0
         BEGIN
             IF @i < 0
                 SET @i = 0 
        
             SET @j = CHARINDEX(';', @FirstStr, @i + 1)
             SET @j = CASE WHEN @j = 0 THEN LEN(@FirstStr) + 1 ELSE @j END 
    
             INSERT INTO #TempMacro_PV VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM (RTRIM (SUBSTRING (@FirstStr, @i + 1, @j - @i - 1))), '*', '%'), '?', '_'))
    
             SET @i = CASE WHEN @j = LEN(@FirstStr) + 1 THEN 0 ELSE @j END END
             SET @FirstStr = CAST(N'"& Code.Parameter_GetCodedAttrValues(Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList2_Values.Value) &"' AS NVARCHAR(4000))
             SET @i = - 1
    
             WHILE @i <> 0
             BEGIN
                 IF @i < 0
                     SET @i = 0
            
                 SET @j = CHARINDEX(';', @FirstStr, @i + 1)
                 SET @j = CASE WHEN @j = 0 THEN LEN(@FirstStr) + 1 ELSE @j
             END 
    
             INSERT INTO #TempMacro_PV2 VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM (RTRIM (SUBSTRING (@FirstStr, @i + 1, @j - @i - 1))), '*', '%'), '?', '_'))
    
             SET @i = CASE WHEN @j = LEN(@FirstStr) + 1 THEN 0 ELSE @j END END 
         SET @FirstStr = CAST(N'"& Code.Parameter_GetCodedAttrValues(Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList3_Values.Value) &"' AS NVARCHAR(4000))
             SET @i = - 1
             WHILE @i <> 0
             BEGIN
             IF @i < 0
                 SET @i = 0 
        
             SET @j = CHARINDEX(';', @FirstStr, @i + 1)
             SET @j = CASE WHEN @j = 0 THEN LEN(@FirstStr) + 1 ELSE @j END 
    
             INSERT INTO #TempMacro_PV3 VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM (RTRIM (SUBSTRING (@FirstStr, @i + 1, @j - @i - 1))), '*', '%'), '?', '_'))
    
             SET @i = CASE WHEN @j = LEN(@FirstStr) + 1 THEN 0 ELSE @j END END
         SET @FirstStr = CAST(N'"& Code.Parameter_GetCodedAttrValues(Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList4_Values.Value) &"' AS NVARCHAR(4000))
             SET @i = - 1
             WHILE @i <> 0
             BEGIN
             IF @i < 0
                 SET @i = 0 
        
             SET @j = CHARINDEX(';', @FirstStr, @i + 1)
             SET @j = CASE WHEN @j = 0 THEN LEN(@FirstStr) + 1 ELSE @j END 
    
             INSERT INTO #TempMacro_PV4 VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM (RTRIM (SUBSTRING (@FirstStr, @i + 1, @j - @i - 1))), '*', '%'), '?', '_'))
    
             SET @i = CASE WHEN @j = LEN(@FirstStr) + 1 THEN 0 ELSE @j END END
         SELECT DISTINCT
             CASE WHEN Parent.ObjectPath collate database_default LIKE '%/' collate database_default THEN SUBSTRING (Parent.ObjectPath, 1, len(Parent.ObjectPath) - 1) ELSE Parent.ObjectPath END  collate database_default AS [ParentName],
             Object.ObjectName AS [ObjectName],
             CAST(
                 CASE
                     WHEN Object.objectpath collate database_default LIKE '%[^\]/%' THEN SUBSTRING(Object.objectpath, 1, len(Object.objectpath) - patindex('%/[^\]%', reverse(Object.objectpath))) collate database_default
                     WHEN Object.objectpath collate database_default LIKE '%,ou=%' THEN SUBSTRING(Object.objectpath, charindex(',', Object.objectpath) + 1, LEN(Object.objectpath)) collate database_default
                     ELSE ''
                 END
                 AS NVARCHAR(2000)
             ) AS [Container],
             pd.Type AS [Type],
             pd2.Type AS [Type2],
         pd3.Type AS [Type3],
         pd4.Type AS [Type4],
             pd.pk AS [PropertyID],
             pd2.pk AS [PropertyID2],
         pd3.pk AS [PropertyID3],
         pd4.pk AS [PropertyID4],
             Object.pk AS [pk]
         INTO
             #TempMacro_V1
         FROM
             ObjectsObjects AS Object   
     INNER JOIN ObjectsPropertyValues AS pv ON Object.pk = pv.objectid
             INNER JOIN PropertyDescriptions AS pd ON pd.pk = pv.PropertyID AND pd.PropertyName = N'"&Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList1.Value &"'
             INNER JOIN(SELECT mask FROM #TempMacro_PV AS pf) AS t1 ON
                 pv.Value_String collate database_default LIKE t1.mask collate database_default
                 OR CAST(pv.Value_Integer AS NVARCHAR(1024)) collate database_default LIKE t1.mask collate database_default
                 OR CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), pv.Value_Time, 120) collate database_default LIKE t1.mask collate database_default
                 OR CAST(pv.Value_Double AS NVARCHAR(1024)) collate database_default LIKE t1.mask collate database_default   
     INNER JOIN ObjectsPropertyValues AS pv2 ON Object.pk = pv2.objectid
             INNER JOIN PropertyDescriptions AS pd2 ON pd2.pk = pv2.PropertyID AND pd2.PropertyName = N'"&Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList2.Value &"'
             INNER JOIN(SELECT mask FROM #TempMacro_PV2 AS pf) AS t2 ON
                 pv2.Value_String collate database_default LIKE t2.mask collate database_default
                 OR CAST(pv2.Value_Integer AS NVARCHAR(1024)) collate database_default LIKE t2.mask collate database_default
                 OR CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), pv2.Value_Time, 120) collate database_default LIKE t2.mask collate database_default
                 OR CAST(pv2.Value_Double AS NVARCHAR(1024)) collate database_default LIKE t2.mask collate database_default
     INNER JOIN ObjectsPropertyValues AS pv3 ON Object.pk = pv3.objectid
             INNER JOIN PropertyDescriptions AS pd3 ON pd3.pk = pv3.PropertyID AND pd3.PropertyName = N'"&Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList3.Value &"'
             INNER JOIN(SELECT mask FROM #TempMacro_PV3 AS pf) AS t3 ON
                 pv3.Value_String collate database_default LIKE t3.mask collate database_default
                 OR CAST(pv3.Value_Integer AS NVARCHAR(1024)) collate database_default LIKE t3.mask collate database_default
                 OR CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), pv3.Value_Time, 120) collate database_default LIKE t3.mask collate database_default
                 OR CAST(pv3.Value_Double AS NVARCHAR(1024)) collate database_default LIKE t3.mask collate database_default  
     INNER JOIN ObjectsPropertyValues AS pv4 ON Object.pk = pv4.objectid
             INNER JOIN PropertyDescriptions AS pd4 ON pd4.pk = pv4.PropertyID AND pd4.PropertyName = N'"&Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList4.Value &"'
             INNER JOIN(SELECT mask FROM #TempMacro_PV4 AS pf) AS t4 ON
                 pv4.Value_String collate database_default LIKE t4.mask collate database_default
                 OR CAST(pv4.Value_Integer AS NVARCHAR(1024)) collate database_default LIKE t4.mask collate database_default
                 OR CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), pv4.Value_Time, 120) collate database_default LIKE t4.mask collate database_default
                 OR CAST(pv4.Value_Double AS NVARCHAR(1024)) collate database_default LIKE t4.mask collate database_default             
         INNER JOIN ObjectsObjects AS Parent ON Object.ObjectParent = Parent.pk
         WHERE
             Object.Tag = 1 AND ISNULL(Object.ObjectPath, '') <> ''
             AND Object.ObjectType = 'User' AND pd.Type IN('VARCHAR','INTEGER','DATETIME','DOUBLE') AND pd2.Type IN('VARCHAR','INTEGER','DATETIME','DOUBLE') AND pd3.Type IN('VARCHAR','INTEGER','DATETIME','DOUBLE')
             AND
             (("& Code.ParamSQL_Parameter_OUObject_Like(Parameters!Parameter_OUObject_Like.Value) &") AND (NOT ("& Code.ParamSQL_Parameter_OUObject_NotLike(Parameters!Parameter_OUObject_NotLike.Value) &")))
             AND
             (("& Code.ParamSQL_Parameter_UserObject_Like(Parameters!Parameter_UserObject_Like.Value) &") AND (NOT("& Code.ParamSQL_Parameter_UserObject_NotLike(Parameters!Parameter_UserObject_NotLike.Value) &")))
         SELECT Object.ParentName AS [ParentName],
             Object.ObjectName AS [ObjectName],
             Object.Container AS [Container],
             CASE Object.Type WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN pv.Value_String
                             WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN CAST(pv.Value_Integer AS NVARCHAR(1024))
                             WHEN 'DATETIME' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), pv.Value_Time, 120)
                             WHEN 'DOUBLE' THEN CAST(pv.Value_Double AS NVARCHAR(1024))
                             ELSE '' END AS [Value],
             pv.ValueNumber AS [ValueNumber],
             CASE Object.Type2 WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN pv2.Value_String
                             WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN CAST(pv2.Value_Integer AS NVARCHAR(1024))
                             WHEN 'DATETIME' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), pv2.Value_Time, 120)
                             WHEN 'DOUBLE' THEN CAST(pv2.Value_Double AS NVARCHAR(1024))
                             ELSE '' END AS [Value2],
             pv2.ValueNumber AS [ValueNumber2],
         CASE Object.Type2 WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN pv3.Value_String
                             WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN CAST(pv3.Value_Integer AS NVARCHAR(1024))
                             WHEN 'DATETIME' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), pv3.Value_Time, 120)
                             WHEN 'DOUBLE' THEN CAST(pv3.Value_Double AS NVARCHAR(1024))
                             ELSE '' END AS [Value3],
         pv3.ValueNumber AS [ValueNumber3],
         CASE Object.Type4 WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN pv4.Value_String
                             WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN CAST(pv4.Value_Integer AS NVARCHAR(1024))
                             WHEN 'DATETIME' THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), pv4.Value_Time, 120)
                             WHEN 'DOUBLE' THEN CAST(pv4.Value_Double AS NVARCHAR(1024))
                             ELSE '' END AS [Value4],
         pv4.ValueNumber AS [ValueNumber4],
             Object.pk AS [pk]
         INTO #TempMacro_V
         FROM
             #TempMacro_V1 AS Object
             INNER JOIN ObjectsPropertyValues AS pv ON Object.pk = pv.objectid AND Object.PropertyID = pv.PropertyID
             INNER JOIN ObjectsPropertyValues AS pv2 ON Object.pk = pv2.objectid AND Object.PropertyID2 = pv2.PropertyID
     INNER JOIN ObjectsPropertyValues AS pv3 ON Object.pk = pv3.objectid AND Object.PropertyID3 = pv3.PropertyID
     INNER JOIN ObjectsPropertyValues AS pv4 ON Object.pk = pv4.objectid AND Object.PropertyID4 = pv4.PropertyID
         SELECT PK, [Value], ValueNumber, Value2, ValueNumber2, Value3, ValueNumber3, Value4, ValueNumber4
         INTO #TempMacro_VV
         FROM #TempMacro_V
         CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idv ON #TempMacro_VV (PK)
         /*Insertion of 08.02.2010 - beginning*/
         DECLARE @CountVal INT, @ValLen INT
         SELECT @CountVal = MAX(ValueNumber) FROM #TempMacro_VV
         SET @ValLen = 1500
         SELECT DISTINCT
             P.PK AS PK,
             CAST(P.[Value] AS NVARCHAR(1500)) AS PValue
         INTO #TempMacro_P1
         FROM #TempMacro_VV AS P
         WHERE P.ValueNumber = 0
         CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX id1 ON #TempMacro_P1 (PK)
         SET @I = 1
         WHILE @I <= @CountVal
         BEGIN
             UPDATE #TempMacro_P1
             SET PValue = CASE WHEN (LEN(PValue) + LEN(P.[Value])) < (@ValLen - 2) THEN PValue + '; ' + P.[Value] ELSE PValue END
             FROM #TempMacro_P1 AS P1
             INNER JOIN #TempMacro_VV AS P ON P1.PK = P.PK
             WHERE P.ValueNumber = @I
    
             SET @I = @I + 1
         END
         DECLARE @CountVal2 INT
         SELECT @CountVal2 = MAX(ValueNumber2) FROM #TempMacro_VV
         SELECT DISTINCT
             P.PK AS PK,
             CAST(P.[Value2] AS NVARCHAR(1500)) AS PValue
         INTO #TempMacro_P2
         FROM #TempMacro_VV AS P
         WHERE P.ValueNumber2 = 0
         CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX id2 ON #TempMacro_P2 (pk)
         SET @I = 1
         WHILE @I <= @CountVal2
         BEGIN
             UPDATE #TempMacro_P2
             SET PValue = CASE WHEN (LEN(PValue) + LEN(P.Value2)) < (@ValLen - 2) THEN PValue + '; ' + P.Value2 ELSE PValue END
             FROM #TempMacro_P2 AS P2
             INNER JOIN #TempMacro_VV AS P ON P2.PK = P.PK
             WHERE P.ValueNumber2 = @I
    
             SET @I = @I + 1
         END
     DECLARE @CountVal3 INT
         SELECT @CountVal3 = MAX(ValueNumber3) FROM #TempMacro_VV
         SET @ValLen = 1500
         SELECT DISTINCT
             P.PK AS PK,
             CAST(P.[Value3] AS NVARCHAR(1500)) AS PValue
         INTO #TempMacro_P3
         FROM #TempMacro_VV AS P
         WHERE P.ValueNumber3 = 0
         CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX id3 ON #TempMacro_P3 (PK)
         SET @I = 1
         WHILE @I <= @CountVal
         BEGIN
             UPDATE #TempMacro_P3
             SET PValue = CASE WHEN (LEN(PValue) + LEN(P.[Value3])) < (@ValLen - 2) THEN PValue + '; ' + P.Value3 ELSE PValue END
             FROM #TempMacro_P3 AS P3
             INNER JOIN #TempMacro_VV AS P ON P3.PK = P.PK
             WHERE P.ValueNumber3 = @I
    
             SET @I = @I + 1
         END
     DECLARE @CountVal4 INT
         SELECT @CountVal4 = MAX(ValueNumber4) FROM #TempMacro_VV
         SET @ValLen = 1500
         SELECT DISTINCT
             P.PK AS PK,
             CAST(P.[Value4] AS NVARCHAR(1500)) AS PValue
         INTO #TempMacro_P4
         FROM #TempMacro_VV AS P
         WHERE P.ValueNumber4 = 0
         CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX id4 ON #TempMacro_P4 (PK)
         SET @I = 1
         WHILE @I <= @CountVal
         BEGIN
             UPDATE #TempMacro_P4
             SET PValue = CASE WHEN (LEN(PValue) + LEN(P.[Value4])) < (@ValLen - 2) THEN PValue + '; ' + P.Value4 ELSE PValue END
             FROM #TempMacro_P4 AS P4
             INNER JOIN #TempMacro_VV AS P ON P4.PK = P.PK
             WHERE P.ValueNumber4 = @I
    
             SET @I = @I + 1
         END
         /*Insertion of 08.02.2010 - end*/
         SELECT
             Objects.ParentName AS [ParentName],
             Objects.ObjectName AS [ObjectName],
             P1.PValue AS [Value],
             N'"&Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList1.Value &"' AS [PropertyName],
             P2.PValue AS Value2,
             N'"&Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList2.Value &"' AS [PropertyName2],
         P3.PValue AS Value3,
             N'"&Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList3.Value &"' AS [PropertyName3],
         P4.PValue AS Value4,
             N'"&Parameters!Parameter_AttrbitesList4.Value &"' AS [PropertyName4],
             1 AS [S],
             Objects.pk AS [pk]
         FROM #TempMacro_P1 AS P1
         INNER JOIN #TempMacro_P2 AS P2 ON P1.PK = P2.PK
     INNER JOIN #TempMacro_P3 AS P3 ON P1.PK = P3.PK
     INNER JOIN #TempMacro_P4 AS P4 ON P1.PK = P4.PK
         LEFT JOIN #TempMacro_V AS Objects ON Objects.PK = P1.PK AND Objects.PK = P2.PK AND Objects.PK = P3.PK AND Objects.PK = P4.PK AND Objects.ValueNumber = 0 AND Objects.ValueNumber2 = 0 AND Objects.ValueNumber3 = 0 AND Objects.ValueNumber4 = 0
         WHERE (" & Code.ParamSQL_Parameter_Domains_In_5_1_Item1(Parameters!Parameter_Domains_In_5_1.Value) & ")
         ORDER BY 1, "& Parameters!Parameter_Sorting.Value &" ASC, 2 ASC    
         DROP TABLE #TempMacro_P1
         DROP TABLE #TempMacro_P2
     DROP TABLE #TempMacro_P3
         DROP TABLE #TempMacro_PV
         DROP TABLE #TempMacro_PV2
     DROP TABLE #TempMacro_PV3
     DROP TABLE #TempMacro_PV4
         DROP TABLE #TempMacro_VV
      ```
````

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to try to read/understand this query with no schema or data available...So, run the query from the SSRS dataset query designer. The results you see there are what will get passed to the report. The the results look OK there then look at filters in your report etc. If the results are different from SSMS, run a trace on the server and capture exactly what is being executed n the server in each instance, from there you might be able to work out what is different

Answer (score 0):

SSRS hates nulls. they have always caused me a lot of problems as well. they dont really work in dropdowns and dont display well. I just add an ISNULL(FIELDNAME, 'NULL') to all fields in the SELECT to remove them

I know its not exactly what you are asking, but it will solve your nondisplay problem.